# Duplicate declaration "Form" - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm using React with two different components: [Formsy](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react) and [React Router Form](https://github.com/insin/react-router-form).
Both have component class called **Form** so, gulp returns in console the following error messsage:
*Duplicate declaration "Form" while parsing file: C:\Users...*
What could be the best way to use both of this components together without conflicts?

Comment: Is your gulp parsing the node_modules directory? or  Is the error from one of your files ?

Comment: no, it's not a gulp in itself problem, the error come from my js file where I import both components: `import { Form } from 'formsy-react';
import Form from 'react-router-form';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as alias` for  Formsy react.

```
Syntax
import { member as alias } from "module-name";


import { Form as FormsyForm } from 'formsy-react';
import Form from 'react-router-form';

render(){
   return( <div>
        <FormsyForm>
           ....
        </FormsyForm>
        <Form>
           ....
        </Form
      </div>
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: the problem is the target of this two components is the same html tag. I would like use  different features of both components in the same html component <Form></Form>.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. When you import as an alias. You need to use the tag FormsyForm for the formsy-react form.

Comment: it should work if both target different html components, but, if I change name of html component one of component class doesn't work